# <t:datatable> Column value changes - JSF

Tags: jsf-2

JSF-2.0  - **specific row's**(eg: 1st row) **column value** (eg: 2nd column of a row) need to be changed **on change of  other column value** (eg: 1st column of a row)

Comment: You forgot to ask a concrete programming question about the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is your question but if I understand correctly you probably could render the other column contents based on their id's. I do though think that you need the whole id of the rendered component including the row number of the id. Otherwise just render the whole table.

PLease confirm if this was the question and if this actually functions...